Why it took 54 ms even though the time complexity was O(n)
I recenty started solving questions on leetcode and came accross this Questions where we had to remove all alphanumeric characters from a string and then check if the string is a palindrome or not.
I tried to keep O(n) time complexity still it took 54 ms which is way too long can someone please explain. Here is the code:
class Solution {
public:
    bool isPalindrome(string s) {
        int n = 0;
        transform(s.begin(),s.end(),s.begin(),::tolower);
        while(s[n] != '\0'){
            if(isalnum(s[n]) == 0 ){
                s.erase(s.begin()+n);
            }
            else{
            n++;
            }
        }

        string check = s;
        reverse(s.begin(),s.end());

        if(s == check){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }

    }
};

I was wanted to know what part of code exaclty is taking time

Your algorithm is not O(n).

It would almost certainly be the while loop, which erases alphanumeric characters in s, one at a time.  Each erase() operation (even if it doesn't reallocate memory) shuffles other characters in the string around, and invalidates all iterators.    In any event, even if your code was O(n) - which it isn't - complexity is not a direct indicator of execution time - it is a limiting case (all it says is that execution time approaches being proportional to n when n is large).

Do not tag this as dsa.  The dsa tag is for Digital Signature Algorithm.

I think the mistake you are making is assuming that any code not written by you doesn't count but that is not true. erase by itself is an O(n) operation, and you have put that inside an O(n) loop. Therefore your code is actually O(n^2).

O(n) time complexity has no bearing on whether the algorithm will take 54 ms.

return std::equal(s.begin(), s.begin() + s.size() / 2, s.rbegin());.

If you're going to use erase, use it in a much better way: s.erase(std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [](char ch) { return !std::isalnum(static_cast<unsigned char>(ch)); }), s.end()); is that entire loop, and without repeated calls to erase.  The goal is to call erase just one time, and the items to erase are all at the end of the string.

I recenty started solving questions on leetcode -- Which once again proves that Leetcode does not teach C++.  If you had known about the algorithm functions such as std::remove_if, plus know that erase() has an overload that takes a begin and end iterator, you would not have written the loop that calls erase on every individual character you want to erase.

All an O(n) operation promises is that it'll take (approximately) the same time, every time. Whether that time is 54ms, 54hours or 54years or something else, every time, is not something that Big O notation tells you.

The complexities of all parts:

Transforming to lowercase: O(N)
Removing non-alphanumeric characters: O(N^2)
Reversing the string: O(N)
Comparing strings: O(N)

You can use two pointers with O(N) time complexity:
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>

// The following block might slightly improve the execution time;
// Can be removed;
static const auto improve_runtime = []()
{
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(nullptr);
    std::cout.tie(nullptr);
    return 0;
}();

struct Solution
{
    static bool isPalindrome(const std::string &s)
    {
        for (int left = 0, right = s.size() - 1; left < right; ++left, --right)
        {
            while (left < right && !std::isalnum(s[left]))
            {
                ++left;
            }

            while (left < right && !std::isalnum(s[right]))
            {
                --right;
            }

            if (std::toupper(s[left]) != std::toupper(s[right]))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << Solution().isPalindrome("A man, a plan, a canal: Panama") << "\n";
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << Solution().isPalindrome("A Santa at NASA") << "\n";
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << Solution().isPalindrome("Taco Cat") << "\n";
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << Solution().isPalindrome("Was it a cat I saw?") << "\n";
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << Solution().isPalindrome("Never odd or even") << "\n";
}


Prints
true
true
true
true
true


Comment:

std::isalnum returns 0 when the argument is not alpha-numeric, and non-zero when it is. While false is equal to 0, non-zero is not necessarily equal to true. So comparing with false is a bit misleading, since the type of the result is not bool; compare with 0, which is what the function actually returns. Or use the usual !isalnum(whatever). – Pete Becker

Why std::int_fast16_t? This makes code slower. – Marek R



#include <stdbool.h> -- Why are you giving C solutions to a question tagged as C++?

Minor point: std::isalnum returns 0 when the argument is not alpha-numeric, and non-zero when it is. While false is equal to 0, non-zero is not necessarily equal to true. So comparing with false is a bit misleading, since the type of the result is not bool; compare with 0, which is what the function actually returns. Or use the usual !isalnum(whatever).

Why std::int_fast16_t? This makes code slower. Also maximum string size is 10^5 so this type will lead to integer overflow.

Now after your last edit code fails on empty string.

Calling erase repeatedly is probably an inefficient way of doing this. When you use call erase on one character, the machine has to move all the following characters one space to the left. This is an O(n) operation. For example, erasing the 'E' in "HELLO" would require the computer to complete all these steps:
0 1 2 3 4
H E L L O

0 1 2 3 4
H   L L O

0 1 2 3 4
H L   L O

0 1 2 3 4
H L L   O

0 1 2 3 4
H L L O

Since you've embedded an erase call in a loop that iterates over your string, your time complexity is O(n*n)=O(n2).
You'll need to find some other way of filtering out the alphanumerics - that much is up to you.
